# Change width of table cell based on dynamic figure

Tags: html, css, html-email, dynamic-html

I'm looking to build a html email with bar charts - I've seen an example where the bars of the charts are just table cells with a width that varies based on a dynamic figure. It was an energy company that sent each customer a bar chart of their energy usage for the month. The energy usage figure is obviously different for everyone and it was this figure that was used to determine the width of the table cell, which was the bar on the chart. I was just wondering how it was done as it's email and javascript can't be used. The email was sent to my gmail account and I've inspected the code but it's still not clear how it's done as gmail renames all the classes and strips a lot of the css from the top styles.

Answer (score 0):

I had done quiet a few some time ago for different companies. For bars being of varied width you can use % as width with background colours. You database should contain a flag which decides which version of the graph to show.

The table width can be percentage so it can scale down on responsive screens. Without an example image or code that's how much I can say. Try and add an image of possible and maybe we can have a look at it properly.